# How can I change part of a PyTorch tensor based on the values of another tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

This question may not be clear, so please ask for clarification in the comments and I will expand.

I have the following tensors of the following shape:

```
mask.size() == torch.Size([1, 400])
clean_input_spectrogram.size() == torch.Size([1, 400, 161])
output.size() == torch.Size([1, 400, 161])
```

`mask` is comprised only of `0` and `1`. Since it's a mask, I want to set the elements of `output` equal to `clean_input_spectrogram` where that relevant `mask` value is `1`.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, where:

- `m` is your mask;
- `x` is your spectogram;
- `o` is your output;

```py
import torch
torch.manual_seed(2020)

m = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0]]).to(torch.int32)
x = torch.rand((1, 3, 2))
o = torch.rand((1, 3, 2))

print(o)
# tensor([[[0.5899, 0.8105],
#          [0.2512, 0.6307],
#          [0.5403, 0.8033]]])
print(x)
# tensor([[[0.4869, 0.1052],
#          [0.5883, 0.1161],
#          [0.4949, 0.2824]]])

o[:, m[0].to(torch.bool), :] = x[:, m[0].to(torch.bool), :]
# or 
# o[:, m[0] == 1, :] = x[:, m[0] == 1, :]

print(o)
# tensor([[[0.5899, 0.8105],
#          [0.5883, 0.1161],
#          [0.5403, 0.8033]]])
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `.to(torch.bool)` does?

Comment: @Shamoon it converts to boolean

Comment: My mask isn't the same dimension as my input / output

Comment: Can I do: `output[mask == 0.0] = input_spectrogram[mask == 0.0]`?

Comment: How would I do it where the mask is 0?

Comment: @Shamoon you can do it in a similar way (see the comments in my answer), but in your question, your mask, spectogram, and output have dim1 = 400. And your question specifically asks for when the mask is equal to 1. Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Basic usage of a mask:

```py
a = torch.zeros([2,])     # tensor([0., 0.])
b = torch.ones([2,]) * 7  # tensor([7., 7.])

m = torch.tensor([True, False])

a[m] = b[m]               # tensor([7., 0.])
```

In this case, you have an extra dimension in `a` and `b`, but not in mask. This is no problem and will be handled automatically due to broadcasting. Example:

```py
a = torch.zeros([2, 161])
b = torch.ones([2, 161]) * 7

m = torch.tensor([True, False])

a[m] = b[m]
print(a)
```